# Perl error trying to load Bugzilla

Tags: perl, installation, bugzilla

My knowledge of Perl is nil but I was trying to install Bugzilla and everything seem to be going along find until I went to load Bugzilla and I got this error followed by the html of the page trying to be loaded.

```
dmake could not be found on the PATH. Please invoke it using the full pathname:

C:\Perl64\site\bin\dmake.exe

or put the Perl\site\bin directory on the PATH with:

path C:\Perl64\site\bin;%PATH%
```

I tried running the command and also added the pathname manually into the Path Environment Varaible but I'm still receiving the error. It could be something as simple as I'm not putting the pathname correctly into Path.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassingly for me, restarting the computer did the trick. I suspect the Path Environment Variables hadn't taken effect so a restart was required to fix this.